# Prepare(for segue: ) not passing data in Realm

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform, real-mode

The `prepare(for segue: )` function runs, but the data is not sent to my destination ViewController. I am getting following error when loading that VC's collection view which has to receive the data:

> Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I have confirmed that the segue type is a **`selection`** segue, the segue identifier is correct, and that the views work as far as displaying dummy data.

First view controller (DrawerVC):

```
    let realm = try! Realm()
    var allDrawers: Results<Drawer>?

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("goToTool segue")
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToTool", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToTool" {
            print("Prepare for segue from drawerVC ran")  // this runs!
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ToolVC
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                destinationVC.selectedDrawer = allDrawers?[indexPath.row]
                print("Selected drawer set to index path")  // doesn't run :(
            }
        } else if segue.identifier == "goToEditCategory" {
            _ = segue.destination as! EditCategoryVC
        }
    }
```

Destination view controller (ToolVC):

```
    let realm = try! Realm()
    var allTools: Results<Tool>?

    var selectedDrawer: Drawer? {
        didSet{
            // doesn't run since selectedDrawer was never set :(
            print("The selected drawer changed from \(oldValue) to \(selectedDrawer?.title)")
            loadTools()
        }
    }

    func loadTools() {
        allTools = selectedDrawer?.tools.sorted(byKeyPath: "title", ascending: false)
        toolCollectionView.reloadData()  // this is where I get the optional value error
    }
```

Comment: How you connected `segue` from storyboard?

Comment: It is a "show" segue.

Comment: I mean it's connected with ViewController? or any other component from your ViewController

Comment: The segue is connected from the table view prototype cell of the first view controller to the destination VC.

Comment: That is causing the issue. You need to connect segue with your ViewController.

Comment: I changed the segue and my selectedDrawer variable is now being updated but I still have the optional error occurring for some reason.

Comment: Optional error was unrelated... I had initially created my segue from the table view prototype cell because it gave me the option to choose a selection vs accessory segue, but that messed it up. Just having a segue directly from the view controller fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a very common mistake.

In the destination view controller you are accessing the table view in `loadTools()` which is not connected yet at the moment you assign the selected drawer. Therefore the table view is `nil` and causes the crash.

A solution is to remove the `didSet` observer

```
var selectedDrawer: Drawer?
```

and load the data in `viewDidLoad`

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let drawer = selectedDrawer {
        allTools = drawer.tools.sorted(byKeyPath: "title", ascending: false)
        toolCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

And if the segue is connected from the cell to the destination view controller remove the `didSelectRowAt` method.